# Android Studios - Adjusting VideoView Size in Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

I've only ever seen questions asking how to full screen the VideoView but what I'm trying to do is have a video playing as only a part of the activity, with some additional elements on the page. How would I go about doing that? It doesn't seem that I have control of the size of the VideoView, I can only shift it around in the designer.

Edit: Additional Info

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.MyActivity">

    <Button
        Default button Stuff    
    />

    <TextView
        Default textview stuff
    />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android: />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As far as ideal proportions go, maybe something like 500 x 400 dp? I can play with numbers after I understand the process.

Comment: in the editor window, at the bottom of the designer,  click on the "Text" button to edit the xml directly.

Comment: @petey What property am i trying to modify? I don't see a maxWidth/maxHeight

Comment: maxWidth/maxHeight will only work on some Views like [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxWidth(int)) and its subclasses.  If you want this on those types of views,  then add the missing lines to your xml.  Otherwise,  consider using layout weights.

Comment: In order to help you further,  can you edit your question, provide us the xml you have now, and with details as to what you are looking for (what proportions the videoview ought to be related to the screen).

Comment: @petey I made some edits, I'm just trying to do some pretty basic things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is something that you'd want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/componentLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="This is a placeholder text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/componentLayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can define the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes as you wish. However, they can not exceed the height or width of the parent layout.

Result:

[image: Result]

Width: 300dp, Height: 400dp

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. I figured it would be painfully obvious!